# Adding block and template in admin page

Tags: admin, template, controllers, blocks

I have successfully added an admin controller which extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` and works, now I am trying to use a block and template.

I expect to see the text "text here", but I don't see any text, I see the Magento admin header/footer with a blank area, at this URL:
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/index.php/admin/c2/index/key/f5b1fd39ee6e77040cb4c6fbe7340ffd/
(Obviously, the link is a localhost link, but I've shown it for verification!)

My namespace is NS1

My module is Component Management

Here's my files.

```
app/code/local/NS1/ComponentManagement/controllers/c2Controller.php

<?php
class NS1_ComponentManagement_c2Controller extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

--

```
app/code/local/NS1/ComponentManagement/Block/Adminhtml/MyBlock.php

<?php
class NS1_ComponentManagement_Block_Adminhtml_ComponentManagement extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    public function methodblock()
    {
        return 'text here';
    }
}
```

--

```
app/design/adminhtml/NS1/ComponentManagement/template/company.php

<?php
echo $this->methodblock();
```

--

```
app/design/adminhtml/NS1/ComponentManagement/layout/adminhtml.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodulename_adminhtml_mymodulename_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="NS1_ComponentManagement/adminhtml_componentmanagement" name="NS1.ComponentManagement" template="company.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mymodulename_adminhtml_mymodulename_index>
</layout>
```

--

```
app/code/local/NS1/ComponentManagement/etc/config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NS1_ComponentManagement>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </NS1_ComponentManagement>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>NS1_ComponentManagement</module>
                 <frontName>test</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <ComponentManagement>
                    <file>test.xml</file>
                </ComponentManagement>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <ComponentManagement>
                <class>NS1_ComponentManagement_Block</class>
            </ComponentManagement>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <ComponentManagement>
                <class>NS1_ComponentManagement_Helper</class>
            </ComponentManagement>
        </helpers>
    </global>
     <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <NS1_ComponentManagement after="Mage_Adminhtml">NS1_ComponentManagement</NS1_ComponentManagement>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two issues here.

**Your layout handle seems wrong**

I think your handle should be something like `adminhtml_componentmanagement_index`

But what you can do is add some debug into your controller to find the right handle. The following snippet added to your controller action `var_dump` all the layout handles on the page so you can validate the correct one.

```
`$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()`
```

**Need to add the admin layout xml**

In your module's config.xml I think you are missing the snippet to add the layout xml files.

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <your_module>
                <file>path/to/layout.xml</file>
            </your_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```